# Merge sort implementation weirdly faster than system sort

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I wrote the following functions to merge sort an array of `Comparable`s. It seems to work well (I am testing the output to make sure it is sorted). It takes about 2.5 sec for 10 million randomly generated strings. However, when I use the system sort by calling `Arrays.sort()`, it takes about 18 seconds. Why this huge discrepancy?

```
private static void merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i = low;
    int j = mid;
    for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
        aux[k] = a[i];
    }
    for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
        if (i < mid) {
            if (j > high) {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            } else {
                if (aux[i].compareTo(aux[j]) <= 0) {
                    a[k] = aux[i++];
                } else if (aux[i].compareTo(aux[j]) > 0) {
                    a[k] = aux[j++];
                }
            }
        } else {
            a[k] = aux[j++];
        }
    }
}

private static void mergesort(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int start, int end) {
    int N = end - start + 1;
    if (N < 2) return;
    int lo = start;
    int mid = start + N/2;
    int hi = end;
    mergesort(a, aux, lo, mid-1);
    mergesort(a, aux, mid, hi);

    merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
}

private static void msort(Comparable[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    if (N < 2) return;
    Comparable[] aux = new Comparable[N];
    //System.arraycopy(a, 0, aux, 0, N);
    mergesort(a, aux, 0, N - 1);
}

private static boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    if (N < 2) return true;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (a[i-1].compareTo(a[i]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static String createRandString(int lo, int hi) {
    int len = myrandgen.uniform(lo, hi+1);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char ch = (char) myrandgen.uniform(97, 123);
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static void sortTester(int inputSize) {
    String[] s = new String[inputSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
        String t = createRandString(5,15);
        s[i] = t;
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Arrays.sort(s);
    msort(s);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (isSorted(s)) {
        System.out.println("Good Sort.");
        System.out.printf("Time taken: %d for %d elements.\n", end - start, inputSize);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Bad Sort.");
    }
}
/**
 * Unit tests merge sort.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sortTester(10000000);
}
```

Comment: [The OpenJDK implementation guarantees `O ( n log n )`performance](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) (this is a resource)

Answer (score 4):

That's because your implementation is not correct. You have

```
private static void merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i = low;
    int j = mid;
    for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
        aux[k] = a[i];
    }
    for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
        ...
```

yet I believe you need:

```
private static void merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i = low;
    int j = mid;
    for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
        aux[k] = a[i++]; // <--- INCREMENT i
    }
    i = low; // <--- RESET i
    ...
```

The demonstration program is [here](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/fd30712323754d4d034979d1d37dfd3c).

The output is

> ```
> Good Sort.
> Time taken: 29846 for 10000000 elements.
> Good.
> Arrays.sort in 25226 ms.
> true
> ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, good catch. I just need to make it aux[k] = a[k] in the for loop.